# If limit of $f'(t)$ approaches $0$, then limit of $f(t)/t$ approaches $0$.

Tags: analysis

> Let $f: (0, \infty) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable. Show that if $\lim_{t \to \infty}f'(t) = 0$, then $\lim_{t \to \infty}\frac{f(t)}{t} = 0$.

I don't really even know where to start. If we take $\epsilon > 0$, there is $M \in \mathbb{R}$ for which $t > M$ implies that $|f'(t)| < \epsilon$. I'm assuming that we should use the same $M$, but I'm not sure what else.

Comment: Hint: use the fundamental theorem of calculus. Can you bound the growth of $f(x)$?

Comment: The context of the problem doesn't involve integration or anti derivatives.

Comment: The limit doesn't *approach* but rather *is*. To say that $f $ approaches $L $ is the same as saying that the limit of $f $ is $L $. Mixing both expressions is meaningless.

Comment: To use LHopital you’re using integrals anyway

Comment: Special case of this question (and its duplicates): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1044668/if-fx-rightarrow-l-as-x-rightarrow-infty-infty-leq-l-leq-infty

Answer (score 3):

Hint: L'Hopital's rule can be applied to $\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{f(t)}{g(t)}$ merely on the condition that $g(t) \to \infty$.

Comment: I did not know that, +1

Comment: @qbert:  Often overlooked. Now in Wikipedia.  Case 2 of general proof [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule)

Answer (score 2):

Fix $m > 0$ and pick $T$ such that for $t > T$, $|f'(t)| < m$. Then for $t > T$, by MVT there exists $c \in (T,t)$ such that $f(t)= f(T) + f'(c)(t - T)$. Hence $f(t)/t = f(T)/t + f'(c)(1 - T/t)$, so $|f(t)/t| < |f(T)|/t + m(1 - T/t)$. For $t$ large enough we can guarantee that $|f(T)|/t < m$, hence $|f(t)/t| < 2m$, and since $m$ was arbitrary we have $|f(t)/t| \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: You're right! Edited.